# How to load content using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to load my database content using ajax and jquery. I already write a javascript and it works correctly but I can't write correctly for ajax jquery. Anyone please give me some example?

my javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getfilter(str){

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div></script";

    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Views/pfolioresult.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script> 

<div class="sprocket-mosaic-header">
    <div class="sprocket-mosaic-filter">
        <ul>
            <li class="all active" data-mosaic-filterby="all" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="all" >All</li>
            <li class="android" data-mosaic-filterby="android" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="android" >Android</li>
            <li class="iOS" data-mosaic-filterby="iOS" onclick="getfilter(this.id)" id="ios" >IOS</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div id="result">
    ok
</div>
```

Comment: start with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
function getfilter(str){

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div></script";

    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "Views/pfolioresult.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { q : str },
        success: function ( responseText ) {
            $("#result").html( responseText );
        }
    });
}
```

**Learn it** from here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: $("#result").html(responseText);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Ajax and Jquery for data load. You can use

```
function getfilter(str){
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
        //path to  php page to get  data
    url:"pathto/getdata.php",
    data: "id="+str,
    success:function(result){

      //here is your success action
      //get data on div  
        $("#result").html(result);
    });
 }
```

We can do this by calling a function onclick as illustrated above or you can use JQuery's onclick event.

Now Get Id in you getdata.php page using $_POST['id'] and  return your database data to ajax success and do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, the easiest would be to use `.load()`

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript">
        function getfilter(str){

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<div class='sparea'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin sparea' ></i><div></script";

            if (str == ""){
              $( "#result" ).html( "" )
              return;
              } 

            var request = $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Views/pfolioresult.php",
               data: { id: str }
            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
               $( "#result" ).html( msg );
            });

           request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
               alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
           });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function getfilter(str){



    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "Views/pfolioresult.php?q="+str,
        type: "GET",
    //  data: serializedData,
        success: function ( responseText ) {
$("#result").html(responseText); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

This code works correctly but suppose i have 10,000 data in database .This code show all data at once after load but how it possible that data show one by one depent on load time  that means when one item load then it show and other continuously show